# moving asp.net membership specific settings to a separate config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to move the asp.net membership/role settings to a separate config file. This is helpful for custom membership providers.

```
<authentication  mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="144600" slidingExpiration="true">
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="TestMembership">
   <providers>
      <add name="TestMembership" type="Test.Membership.TestMembership">
   </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TestRole"
             cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".Test" cookieTimeout="1440"
             cookiePath="/">
   <providers>
      <add name="TestRole" type="Test.Membership.TestRole" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: sorry, i was trying to do that... thanks for explaining that. edited it.

Comment: @marc_s Agree but have you found that the system doesn't really parse Web.config (possibly all XML) markup correctly?  I've had problems with this in the past.

Comment: @pseudocoder: you need to be aware of two things: (1) you can externalize configuration sections, but not section groups (e.g. you cannot externalize the entire `<system.web>`), and (2) the Visual Studio editor doesn't like the `configSource=` attribute and falsely underlines it with a red squiggly - but that's jsut a shortcoming of the VS editor (and its syntax checking)

Comment: @marc_s I'm talking about the stackoverflow posting system, not VS ;)

Comment: @pseudocoder: ah, okay - just highlight your lines of XML and press the "code" button ( ` { ... } ` ) on the editor toolbar - or just simply indent your XML by at least four spaces - works like a charm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any .NET configuration section can be externalized - try this:

```
<authentication configSource="auth.config" />
<membership configSource="members.config" />
<roleManager configSource="roles.config" />
```

or whatever names you want to use.

The individual files need to contain the whole section that you've externalized:

**auth.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<authentication  mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="144600" slidingExpiration="true">
</authentication>
```

**members.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<membership defaultProvider="TestMembership">
   <providers>
      <add name="TestMembership" type="Test.Membership.TestMembership">
   </providers>
</membership>
```

**roles.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TestRole"
             cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".Test" cookieTimeout="1440"
             cookiePath="/">
   <providers>
      <add name="TestRole" type="Test.Membership.TestRole" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Damn you for posting the answer I was just about to post

Comment: is it possible to club them all into one configFile instead of having auth.config, roles.config etc?

Comment: @coder.net: no - one files per config section - it works only that way, sorry

Comment: ok, thanks. That is not ideal, will leave it in the web.config then.