# Moving asp.net membership web.config settings to Database Is this even possible?

Tags: c#, sql, web-config, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am hoping for fruitful answer to this. How should i move the settings provided in web.config for asp.net membership into a database for cross application customization. For example membership information include below

```
  <providers>
    <add 
      name="OdbcProvider" 
      type="Samples.AspNet.Membership.OdbcMembershipProvider" 
      connectionStringName="OdbcServices"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

#### Extra

.NET 2.0

ASP.NET  2.0

#### Related

[moving asp.net membership specific settings to a separate config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834269/moving-asp-net-membership-specific-settings-to-a-separate-config-file)

Comment: +1, see http://devspade.com/index.php/2010/06/28/using-dynamic-connection-strings-with-the-asp-net-sql-membership-provider/

Comment: @Andomar Ok. hmmm, but still the web.config expects `connectionstringname` to contain something. isn't it?

Comment: That's up to you, your custom provider can retrieve the connection string from any place it wants, including another database.

Comment: @Andomar i will let you know after i try this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can! We have done this successfully.

You can do it in a few ways, one is to inject whichever properties you need into an instance of the provider (this example assumes you are using `SqlMembershipProvider` and shows how you can inject the connection string, but you can take a look at the source of `OdbcMembershipProvider` to get an idea where to do this yourself):

```
public static void InjectConnectionStringIntoSqlMembershipProvider(SqlMembershipProvider provider, string connectionString) {
    Type t = typeof(SqlMembershipProvider);
    FieldInfo fi = t.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fi == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid private identifier.");
    fi.SetValue(provider, connectionString);
}
```

Or, you can create your own provider by creating a class that inherits `MembershipProvider`.

Or, as the link from @Andomar suggests, you can inherit from any implementation of `MembershipProvider` (such as `SqlMembershipProvider`, amongst others), to get what you want.

We have done all three over the years depending on how much customisation was required.

Comment: Reflection always has it's fruits :)